# IBM Mobilefirst: Issue in calling a service from adapter with basic auth

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a service call thats being called from my adapter and that particular service call is being protected by Basic auth. So I am adding the following code in adapter XML to help all the service calls from this adapter to do the Basic Auth validation.

```
<wl:adapter name="adapter" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration" xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

    <displayName>adapter</displayName>
    <description>adapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>myweb.com</domain>
            <!-- <port>443</port> -->

            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>

            <authentication>
                <basic />
                <serverIdentity>
                    <username>123-123-123-123</username>
                    <password>12334445!</password>
                </serverIdentity>

            </authentication>

            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific 
                certificate from key store <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword> -->
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="procedure1" securityTest="wl_unprotected"
        connectAs="server" />
    <procedure name="procedure2" securityTest="wl_unprotected"
        connectAs="server" />
</wl:adapter>
```

When i trying hitting service by using the above xml it gives me Invalid Authorization. But when i added it manually to the header of my service call in the js code it gets through as below.

```
       headers: {Authorization: "Basic MTIzLTEyMy0xMjMtMTIzOjEyMzQ1NiE="}
```

can some body help me in understanding what could be the issue. Will there be some issue **if i keep special characters in the XML. How do i make it work.**

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adapter request with the `Authorization` header will be sent only if the destination service returns 401 or 403 first. If you are able to change the response code of that service, this may be a solution for you. Otherwise, continue with adding the `Authorization` header as you do, which as you say seems to work.